# Print numbers until a negative number is entered

Tags: c

My problem is not related to `scanf();`

For example: input -> `542-4Output` -> `5,4,2,-4`

I mean, print until negative number with negative number. It's okey until negative number, but I want to print negative number too. How can I do ? Please help me. I used `getchar()`, `isdigit()`, `int a=x-'0'`

```
char x =getchar();
while(isdigit(x)){
    int a=x-'0';
    printf("%d,",a);
    x=getchar();
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how scanf is related. Can you clarify what your inputs and outputs and expected outputs are for the code that you have in the question?

Comment: My input is 458-1715, my output is 4 5 8 -1, Each number is separate, when I enter minus value, my program will stop and, prints until minus number and minus number. after minus numbers are not print

Comment: What should "12+34-56yz" print?  or "12--34yz"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit(x)` will not be true for `'-'`, so you need to test for that separately.

Since you want to stop after the first negative number, you need to set a flag when you read the `-`, so you don't keep reading other negative numbers.

```
int neg = 0;
char x = getchar();
while (isdigit(x) || x == '-') {
    if (x == '-') {
        neg = 1;
    } else {
        int a = x - '0';
        if (neg) {
            a = -a;
        }
        printf("%d", a);
        if (neg) {
            break;
        }
    x = getchar();
}
```

Comment: It is not work. when my input 452-1, my outout 4 5 2 -3 1, what I test, always in my output have -3 :)

Comment: I've changed it so it breaks out of the loop after the first number after negative.

Comment: This code is a mess if(neg) two times inside the else!!!! What for? The 'break' makes the code unstructured and all the numbers after the minus sign are not printed (including the sign). Unlesse in don't understand what the OP wants

Comment: @user7140484 It's because he wants to print the next number after the `-`. So I can't stop the loop immediately when reading `-`, I have to set a flag, use that to negate the next number, and then stop. Another way would be to just have do `if (x == '-') { read another character; print its negative; break; }`

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` reads a single character at a time. You will get '5', '4', '2', and '-'.

`isdigit(x)` doesn't work for the '-', so the loop terminates there.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char x = getchar();
    int a;
    while (x != '\n')
    {
        if (isdigit(x))
        {
            a = x - '0';
            printf("%d,", a);
        }
        else
            printf("%c", x);

        x = getchar();
    } 

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: @SefaTaşcan: if you like the answer, upvote them and tag as accepted, for others that have the same problem.